# Getting keys of nested json string in python

Tags: python, json, key

```
{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"name": "Cake",
"ppu": 0.55,
"batters":
    {
        "batter":
            [
                { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
            ]
    },
"topping":
    [
        { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
        { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
```

}

Concider above json string, I want to get all keys from this json string with proper hierarchy like

id ,
type,
name, 
ppu,
batter,

then in batters :
batter,
topping

in batter: id, type

in topping: id, type

I am using python, is there any way out to do the purpose?

Comment: if this is a string then use `data = json.loads(string)` to convert it into object and then use `data["id"]`, `data["batters"]["batter"][0]["id"]`, etc.

Comment: I need generic code to get keys of any json this one is just an example

Comment: `data.keys()` gives you `id , type, name, ppu, batters, topping` and then you have to check type of `data["id"]`, `data["type"]` etc - if it is dictionary then you have to get (for example) `data["batters"].keys()` and check types again. if it is list then you have to check type for `data["topping"][0]`, `data["topping"][1]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks buddy its working perfectly fine :-)
Now I am trying to build a generic recursive function  OR some nested for loops  to output keys on each level of nesting, can you please help me ?

I am not able to do job for 3 or more levels of nesting

Answer (score -2):

If this is a string just try:

```
import json
json.loads(your_variable)
```

If this is a dict parse it into string and use method from above.

Comment: If you assign this to variable just access by variable[key].